# "ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \right." in align* enviroment

Tags: errors, vertical-alignment, align

Why do I get a "ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \right." in the following `align*` environment?

```
\begin{align*}
    \int\left[\left(\der{E_z}{y}-\der{E_y}{z}-\mu\der{\alpha}{t}\right)\alpha&+\left(\der{E_x}{z}-\der{E_x}{x}-\mu\der{\beta}{t}\right)\beta\\
    &+\left(\der{E_y}{x}-\der{E_x}{y}-\mu\der{\gamma}{t}\right)\gamma\left.\vphantom{\left(\der{E_y}{x}}\right]d\omega=0.
    \end{align*}
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Out of curiosity: How is `\der` defined?

Comment: @Mico: `\newcommand{\der}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case where `multline*` should be used; in any case you can't have unbalanced `\left` or `\right` in one of the lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\der}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
\int\biggl[
  \left(\der{E_z}{y}-\der{E_y}{z}-\mu\der{\alpha}{t}\right)\alpha
   +\left(\der{E_x}{z}-\der{E_x}{x}-\mu\der{\beta}{t}\right)\beta +{}\\
  \left(\der{E_y}{x}-\der{E_x}{y}-\mu\der{\gamma}{t}\right)\gamma
\biggr]\,d\omega=0.
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

(I guessed at the definition of `\der`.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted alignment. (Yes, your guess of `\der` is right. ☺)

Comment: @Geremia No, you don't want vertical alignment. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Every `\left` needs to be matched with a corresponding `\right`:

```
\begin{align*}
\int\left[\left(\der{E_z}{y}-\der{E_y}{z}-\mu\der{\alpha}{t}\right)\alpha\right.&+\left(\der{E_x}{z}-\der{E_x}{x}-\mu\der{\beta}{t}\right)\beta\\
&+\left(\der{E_y}{x}-\der{E_x}{y}-\mu\der{\gamma}{t}\right)\gamma\left.\vphantom{\left(\der{E_y}{x}\right)}\right]d\omega=0.
\end{align*}
```