# Why can't I break this formula into two lines?

Tags: line-breaking, align

```
\begin{align}
V_{\alpha \beta} = \left\langle (K_{il} E_{i j}^{\alpha} K_{j m} \delta_l \delta_m + 2 \epsilon_i \delta_m E_{i j}^\alpha K_{j m} + \epsilon_i \epsilon_j E_{i j}^{\alpha} - N_{i j} E_{i j}^\alpha K_{i l} E_{i j}^{\alpha} K_{j m} \xi_{l m} ) 
 (K_{i'l'} E_{i' j'}^{\beta} K_{j' m'} \delta_l' \delta_m' + 2 \epsilon_i' \delta_m' E_{i' j'}^\beta K_{j' m'} + \epsilon_i' \epsilon_j' E_{i' j'}^{\beta} - N_{i' j'} E_{i' j'}^\beta K_{i' l'} E_{i' j'}^{\beta} K_{j' m'} \xi_{l' m'} ) \right\rangle 
\end{align}
```

I woud like to break this long expression with `\\` in correspondence of the passage between `)` and `(`. But it does not work, producing

```
Extra }, or forgotten \right
```

which I don't get if I don't use `\\`. How can I solve it?

Comment: See this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136914/3954

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does the answer in the question that Gonzalo linked to solve your problem for you? If so, we will probably close this question as a duplicate of that one, but it would be nice to get some feedback from you to make sure that it does solve your problem before we close it as a duplicate. If it doesn't solve your problem, you might need to provide more information, perhaps a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).